# Passing data to view with Action Filter and AJAX post ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I have an action filter that checks if the user has more than a certain amount reputation points, but if they don't have enough the action cannot be run and an error message needs to be shown in the partial view.

I have tried using `ViewBag`, `ViewData`, and `TempData`, but they all don't get to the partial (I assume this is because it is an ajax post).

Is there any way to get a message to show on the screen.

Here is my action filter:

```
public class CheckUserForRepAmountForumPostAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string ErrorMessageSuffix { get; set; }
    public int Rep { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var reputationPointService = new ReputationPointService();
        var rep = reputationPointService.GetAllRepPontsForUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);


        var errorMessage = $"You need {Rep.ToString()} reputation {ErrorMessageSuffix}";
        if (!(rep >= Rep))
        {
            var controller = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            filterContext.Controller.TempData["ErrorMessage"] = errorMessage;
            filterContext.Result = new PartialViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "~/Views/" + controller + "/" + ActionName,
                TempData = new TempDataDictionary
                {
                    { "ErrorMessage", errorMessage}
                }

            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your partial view as well.